# Resizing Slideshow Images In A JavaScript Array To Fit Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

My first post, so apologies if the formatting is bad.

I have a project where I'm attempting to create a slideshow using Javascript. I've placed the images into an array and got the slideshow running.

The problem I'm facing is that the images are much larger than the viewport. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569192/image-resize-to-fit-screen) post as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385657/get-the-clientwidth-and-clientheight-of-resized-image) post and many others. They address the issue of re-sizing, but not for images in arrays or the solution requires adding an image to the HTML, which is not what I'm trying to do. I've attempted to use CSS, but it does not work and adding lines in the javascript using

$("#libImage").style.width = '50%';
$("#libImage").style.height = 'auto';

only changes the size of what you can see of the image, not the image itself. Is this even possible for what I'm trying to do and if so, what and where should I use it get the results that I want?

Thank you very much for the help.

HTML

```
<div id="libImage"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var images = ["../images/lib-orange.jpg", "../images/lib-main.jpg", "../images/lib-powel.jpg", "../images/lib-ostrander.jpg"];

    $(function () {
        var i = 0;
        $("#libImage").css("background", "url(images/" + images[i] + ")");
         setInterval(function () {
            i++;
            if (i == images.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            $("#libImage").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).css("background", "url(images/" + images[i] + ")");
                $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Thanks for the response, sorry for the delay. Its not the same effect that I got, but its the same problem. The pictures are not showing up scaled to the size of the viewport.

https://jsfiddle.net/e6ywm5j2/5/

Comment: Can you provide a working example please. I'm a bit confused about the resizing you're trying to do. You want to resize the actual image and display the newly resized image? Or just make it fit the box?

Comment: @CJdriver I would like to have the images fit whatever size the viewport is. So yes, resize the images and then display the images based on the size of the viewport. Again, thanks for the reply.

Comment: `div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}` should fix the problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093740/4891892)

Comment: Hi @PavanKumarJorrigala , I've tried that before and it fits the container to the viewport, but not the image. https://jsfiddle.net/e6ywm5j2/20/ updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `background: url()` I used `img` tag

```
<div id="libImage"><img src="" ></div>
```

and replace `$("#libImage").css("background", "url(images/" + images[i] + ")");` with `$("#libImage img").prop("src", images[i]);`

And css changes are:

```
div { width: 100%; height: 100vh; text-align: center; }

img {
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e6ywm5j2/69/)

Comment: Thats it! Thanks so much!